# Is this a penalty?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console

In the last months I noted that one of my main keywords (website section) was dropping quickly, did I do maybe something wrong? For instance to add a menu entry and a h1 with the exact keyword which is actually the real name of the section?

[image: stats]

Comment: Actually, the website purpose is to give you public and local IP address, and is exactly what it does. The keyword is: 'what is my local ip'... so... If you search that, and all what you get is exactly that... hehe maybe Google is just doing the things wrongly or maybe I have to find the ways to retain the user a bit longer in the website... maybe offering some additional services or so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to tell based solely on the information given.

More likely it's Google's recent spurt of updates.  However, based on what I see, you have only occasional click through by users in spite of a fairly consistent impression rate and positioning.  It's my belief that Google interprets low click through as not answering the user's question.  As a result, they may choose to show your links less.

CTR and SEO ranking is a controversial topic so you may want to look at this post of [CTR and Google rankings](https://moz.com/blog/does-organic-ctr-impact-seo-rankings-new-data) and this question here on SE [How can CTR affect SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/58365/how-can-ctr-click-through-rate-affect-seo-web-site-rank) for different people's opinions.